# IOS 5 Crash @ [self.navigationController pushViewController:vcSummary animated:YES ];

Tags: iphone, xcode, crash, ios5, pushviewcontroller

**`[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcSummary animated:YES ];`** is leading to my application crash (which is already in app store) on device, but working perfectly on my iPhone 5.0 simulator.

Please suggest is there any way to find out why crash is happening?

How to debug on iPhone i.e **can i run application on iPhone and see the logs on iPhone itself?**

**Code:-**

```
AirportInfoSummaryController *vcSummary = [[AirportInfoSummaryController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:vcSummary animated:YES ];
```

`AirportInfoSummaryController` has a table view with each row loaded with a table view cell (three rows have 3 xib's loaded)

Crash Log I am Getting:-[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can view the device logs through Xcode > Organiser > Devices. You can also symbolicate your crash logs there, assuming that you did build and archive and thus the dSYM file still exists. (Symbolication links the 'gibberish' that the crash log outputs to actual lines of code to help you debug.)